# EventEmitter angular 2 catching event and debugging

Tags: typescript, angular

I have write a simple event emitter but it seems not working, so that's the code:

## AppComponent

and main app component

```
@Component({
    selector:'my-app',
    templateUrl:'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/app.component.css'],
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,MenuBar],
})
export class AppComponent{
    title:'My App'
    activated(event:Routes){
        console.log('activated');
        console.log(received)
    }
}
```

## AppComponent.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<menu-bar (activate)="activated($event)"></menu-bar>
<div class="router-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

## Download

```
@Component({
    .... component's configurations....
})
class Download implements OnInit{
    ... some attributes and code ...;

    @Output() activate:EventEmitter <Routes>= new EventEmitter<Routes>();
    r:Routes={};
    test(): void{
        console.log('emit start')
        console.log(this.r);
        try{
            this.activate.emit(this.r)
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log('sent')
    }
}
```

the download component is inside a router-outlet.
So first of all, I see all the console.log messages of the Download component but I see no message in the app component is there any reason? What am I doing wrong?
Second one, I think (but maybe I'm wrong) that the problem is in the message propagations, so I would like to debug the emit and catch the events globally, is it possible? And if it is so, how shall I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events from `@Outputs()` don't bubble and are useless in routed components.

You can only use it like `<download-component (activate)="..."` (listening on the component directly)

You can use a shared service to communicate between routed components and parent components like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html